# Issue with Rating when using Firebase with React

Tags: reactjs, firebase, google-cloud-firestore

I have made a feedback form that includes the 5 star Rating component. However, when I try and click on the stars, it doesn't save the stars I have clicked on and when I try and send it to the database, it doesn't add the value to firebase. I am not too sure why but this is my code:

```
class FeedbackForm extends Component {
    constructor() {
        super();
        this.state = {
            bRating: 0,
            eRating: 0,
            pRating: 0,
            vRating: 0
        };
    }

    updateInput = e => {
        this.setState({
            [e.target.name]: e.target.value
            
        });
        console.log(e)
    }

    addBooking = e => {
        e.preventDefault();
        const db = firebase.firestore();
        const userRef = db.collection("Bookings").add({
            bRating: this.state.bRating,
            eRating: this.state.eRating,
            pRating: this.state.pRating,
            vRating: this.state.vRating
        });
        this.setState({
            bRating: "",
            eRating: "",
            pRating: "",
            vRating: ""
        });
    };

    getBooking = e => {
        const db = firebase.firestore();
        db.collection("Bookings")
            .get()
            .then(querySnapshot => {
                const data = querySnapshot.docs.map(doc => doc.data());
                console.log(data); 
            });
    }

    render() {
        const { collapseID } = this.state;

        return (
            <div>
                <form onSubmit={this.addBooking}>

                                <tr>
                                    <td>
                                        <Box component="fieldset" mb={3} borderColor="transparent">
                                            <Rating
                                                style={{ fontSize: '2em' }}
                                                name="simple-controlled1"
                                                value={this.state.bRating}
                                                onChange={this.updateInput}
                                            />
                                        </Box>
                                    </td>
                                    <td>
                                        <Box component="fieldset" mb={3} borderColor="transparent">
                                            <Rating
                                                style={{ fontSize: '2em' }}
                                                name="simple-controlled2"
                                                value={this.state.vRating}
                                                onChange={this.updateInput}
                                            />
                                        </Box>
                                    </td>
                                </tr>
```

Any help would be appreciated, thanks!

Comment: What do you get in  `[e.target.name]` ?

Comment: @KToxcon ```["simple-controlled1"]```

Comment: None of your states is called that. It may be the problem.
Your setting a state that doesn't exists.

Comment: @KToxcon I cant believe I didn't realise that haha. That fixed the issue, thank you so much!

Comment: Hi @KToxcon, since you solved the issue you can post it an answer to help others if they will encounter the same issue.